Is the $FART memecoin a layer 2 blockchain of the BASE blockchain ($BASE) and how does it work in relation to Ethereum ($ETH)?
$FART is a memecoin/$hitcoin that was launched on December 23rd, 2024, two days before Christmas. I wanted to know more about it and assumed that is blockchain is based on BASE, which is, itself, a blockchain that is a layer-2 blockchain solution built on the Ethereum protocol as the L1 mainchain blockchain. But, I am unsure where $FART belongs here if it does belong here. Because the Layer 1 for BASE is Ethereum, I thought this was the appropriate place to ask this question.
That said, as context, I wanted to discuss the $FART memecoin more:
$FART has an ominous description. Here is the quote of the description:

"Fart coin is a meme coin with a mysterious connection to the concept
of "gas" in blockchain theory, but the main purpose is based on
humour. "It's silent but wealthy." This is the best choice to
represent this Fart Coin. Fart Coin is simply launching, but will try
to make all meme lovers to another Stephen Colbert."

I think this description may be ominous, suggesting that it is a scamcoin memecoin. But, the price behaviour/performance is too good to be true with explosive, multi-multiple upsides daily thus far (about a week in). That said, The reason why I think this description is ominous despite the performance is that, after reading said description,the statement "silent but wealthy" sounds like the author intends to indicate that the people who buy it may see a large paper gain as it explodes upward (and become "wealthy"), but won't be able to use that money or swap it (hence becoming "silent" with a silent paper gain), hence the phrasing "it's silent but wealthy". Later, the author indicate that $FART "will try to make all meme lovers to another Stephen Colbert", which, to me, is also ominous because Mr. Stephen Colbert was a bitcoin basher earlier on in 2013, so the author may suggest that the inability to swap $FART may make a person who invested in it (potentially a "meme lover") skeptical, as Mr. Stephen Colbert is skeptical. This is my analysis on the description--as there is not much else on the memecoin in terms of its utility and UCC.
Now, my question is, how does $FART work in connection to the BASE network and the Ethereum network in terms of the blockchain layer?
